# how to bind multidimensional array of different values to a datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid

I have a datagrid in my application and I would like to bind multidimensional array of bool items to the grid.

how to bind the following items to the datagrid ItemsSource ?

for e.g

```
        bool[,] matrix = new bool[10, 22];

        matrix[0, 1] = true;
        matrix[0, 2] = false;
        matrix[0, 3] = true;
        matrix[1, 1] = false;
        matrix[1, 3] = true;
```

What i have tried, and I see an empty datagrid

```
 public MatrixPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        bool[,] matrix = new bool[5, 5];

        matrix[0, 1] = true;
        matrix[0, 2] = false;            
        matrix[0, 3] = true;

        var datsource = (from i in Enumerable.Range(0, matrix.GetLength(0))
                         select new clsdatasource(matrix[0, 1], matrix[0, 2], matrix[0, 3])).ToList();

        Matrix_datagrid.ItemsSource = datsource;
    }

    public class clsdatasource
    {
        public bool str1 { get; set; }
        public bool str2 { get; set; }
        public bool str3 { get; set; }

        public clsdatasource(bool s1, bool s2, bool s3)
        {
            this.str1 = s1;
            this.str2 = s2;
            this.str3 = s3;
        }
      }
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have error in the linq expression, you should use `i` variable instead of `0`:

```
var datsource = (from i in Enumerable.Range(0, matrix.GetLength(0))
                    select new clsdatasource(matrix[i, 1], matrix[i, 2], matrix[i, 3])).ToList();
```

In xaml I have only following code and everything working very well.

```
<DataGrid  Name="Matrix_datagrid" />
```

Example:

```
bool[,] matrix = new bool[5, 5];

matrix[0, 1] = true;
matrix[0, 2] = false;
matrix[0, 3] = true;
matrix[1, 1] = true;
matrix[2, 2] = true;
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: the following code matrix[i,0] ,[i,1],[i,2] fills only the first row.. what will be the condition if I want to fill the second row and the other rows so on... ?? do I have to use another statement ?

Comment: @user1221765 code with variable `i` move data exactly from `matrix`. So if you want to fill second row and the other rows, you should in the first of all populate data in `matrix`. Check my answer again.